# where to see the error message from RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I created a trigger in an Oracle database. This trigger will be executed before a insert procedure, to kill all duplicate data. The procedure is executed by a C# application.

```
TRIGGER Kill_Duplicates

BEGIN

IF ( xxx ) THEN
  Raise_application_error(-22222, ' is duplicate!');
END IF;

END
```

1. Where to read the message from Raise_application_error? for example, if some duplicates data enter the database, it triggers the Raise_application_error, where to read this - "(-22222, ' is duplicate!')"?
2. Is there any ways to debug trigger? if my trigger wasn't correct, for example, syntax problem, logic problem, then how to read the exception message of the trigger itself? how would i know and how to get the exceptions/errors?

Comment: What database are you using? Any answer would depend on that information. Also, the place to see the error message would be in your front-end application (that's the `APPLICATION` in `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`). Whether there's a way to debug will, once again, depend on the database you're using. Please remember we can't read your mind or see your screen from where we are, so we only have the information you give us to use to try and help you. :-)

Comment: how about you make it better *this* time...

Comment: Good comment! Make it better this time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception will be passed to the session that executed the DML statement that caused the trigger to be executed.

I'm suspicious that your error message suggests that you are trying to enforce integrity with a trigger. That's usually a Bad Thing.

Comment: Where can I read the actual exception/error? the session? where is that?sorry im a freshman

Comment: It depends entirely on the application, but basically there has to be some code somewhere that performs the insert or whatever, so you need to find that.

Comment: The insert code is a procedure in SQL developer, can i read the exception in SQL developer?

Comment: Is the procedure executed from SQL developer,and if so how?

Comment: The procedure is executed in C# code. The error message will pass to the session when the C# code executing the procedure? so , i need listen the C# code to get the error message?